# Visual Studio Code - Compare two csv and find data that not in the two files

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code

So, I have two csv files that I need to compare. However, I am not sure if I am using `compare active file` in Visual Code will help me.

File 1.csv --> the starting point

```
id,name
12a,mark
134,jon
151,pete
z18,sab
329,lin
m32,sam
kla,kop
l5h,ming
```

File 2.csv --> modified one, basically made some changes (delete two id)

```
id,name
12a,mark
134,jon
151,pete
l5h,ming
kla,kop
329,lin
```

So, I want to use visual code to compare between these two files and find out which line from the 1.csv that already been removed. If I use `compare active file` in visual code, it only gave me which line that different from the original one. But I cannot find between the original file (1.csv) and the modified one (2.csv), which data/id has been removed.

I am not sure whether visual code can do this or what keyword that I need to use in google to find this solution. So I am wondering if anyone could help me with this.

Ps

- The real files that I need to deal with in the same situation have more than a thousand id.
- Sorry if this has been resolved or asked somewhere in StackOverflow, English is not my native and I don't know what keyword that I should use in StackOverflow for this.

Thanks!

Comment: In the context menu of the Explorer you can choose **Select for compare** and **Compare with selected** to get a diff between files

Answer (score 2):

If you multi-select (Ctrl+Left-Click on Windows) both files (file1.csv, file2.csv) in the VS Code (File) Explorer window, then select `Compare Selected` from the right-click menu in the (File)Explorer window, a diff window will open with the comparison you desire.

Note the first-selected file will appear on the left pane of the diff window.